# How to center a second HStack View?

Tags: swiftui

I'm having trouble centering that second "Date" `Text` within the `HStack`.  As you can see, in the image, it is a bit farther to the left. I want only the second view to be centered in the HStack.  I want the first View to be latched to leading.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DaySummariesBarChart: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Date")
                .font(.footnote)
            Text("Date")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct BarChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DaySummariesBarChart()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty clean way to do it:

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Text("Date")
      .font(.footnote)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    Text("Date")
   }
}
```

The first `Text` gets a maxWidth of `infinity`, so it takes up the whole space, but is aligned to `.leading`.

The second `Text` is centered by default in the `ZStack`.

[image]

Comment: Haha.  This actually works.  I would still upvote working alternatives.

Comment: You could also look into alignment guides: https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/

Answer (score 0):

The Spacer() moves the Views to the left. Your problem should be solved by adding another Spacer() on the other side.

```swift
struct DaySummariesBarChart: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Date")
                .font(.footnote)
            Text("Date")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want only the second view to be centered in the HStack.  I want the first View to be latched to leading. Just updated the question.  ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GeometryReader to make the width of the Views exactly half and therefore center the second one.

```swift
struct DaySummariesBarChart: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Text("Date")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
                Text("Date")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be centering the texts to their respective spaces in the HStack, not relative to the HStack itself.